# Problem debugging ROS nodes on Mac OS X

Tags: ros, catkin, gdb, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

I am on Mac OS X 10.11.4, ROS Jade and have some strange problems debugging ROS nodes with gdb or lldb. Namely, debugger is not able to locate ROS related shared libraries.

Here is gdb output for example:

```
    Starting program: /Users/plistov/EPFL/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/test_package/lib/test_package/ekf_node 
dyld: Library not loaded: libtf2_ros.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/plistov/EPFL/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/test_package/lib/test_package/ekf_node
  Reason: image not found

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff5fc01075 in ?? ()
```

While DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the folder containing this lib. Furthermore, I did not manage to launch standard ROS nodes. Rosbag for instance:

```
(gdb) exec-file rosbag
"/Users/plistov/EPFL/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/install/bin/rosbag": not in executable format: File format not recognised
```

I have not experienced any problems debugging non-ROS related applications on my computer before. I, therefore, will very appreciate any hint or advice.

Thanks,
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258775/problem-debugging-ros-nodes-on-mac-os-x/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue seems to be OS specific. Well explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587130/why-doesnt-lldb-forward-my-environment-variable-anymore). Had to switch to lldb though.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0